# Should I upgrade python 2.7.3 to 2.7.4

Tags: python

The reason I ask is that some of the packages I have installed were specific to 2.7.3 as windows installers from PyPI.

Would these need to be re-installed or would pip update these?

Thanks.

Comment: Reasonable question, not a great title.

Answer (score 0):

A version number of Python is in `x.y.z` format, eg: `2.7.4`.

- `x` means major release, it often broke a lot of things.
- `y` means minjor release, it often changed a few APIs.
- `z` means bug-fix release, just fixed some bug, all APIs are compatible with earlier version.

**So, the quick answer is: Python 2.7.4 just a bug-fix release of 2.7 series, you *could* and *should* upgrade to that version without break anything. Generally, you needn't do any extra work, too.**

Unfortunately, if Python release a version with a different `y` number a few days ago, although the modules for the earlier version should works with some modifies (if you are lucky enough, you don't need to modify the code), but the modules should rebuild to work on the latest Python.

That means you have to wait for a new build, that takes about a month, it depends on the maintainers and packagers. Or you have to build from source by yourself. So, you could just keep the current version of Python you used, and upgrade it later.

If they released a version with different `x` number, maybe Python changes a lots of APIs, break almost everything. You need to think about it carefully. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think this is right. The binary interface is not supposed to change between minor point releases - so you should be able to use existing 2.7 binaries on 2.7.4 (that is why the binaries have only 2.7 or 2.6 in the name)